# Need help on how to get 2 or more OnTriggerEnter2D i am trying to make the player respawn. It also has the movement controls there two

Tags: c#

`
// this was for jumping
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
{
isJumping = false;
}
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
{
isJumping = true;
}
}

```
// for respawing
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "FallDetector")
    {
        transform.position = respawnPoint;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: is this for unity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.